# Cakephp return only one record using findby method

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a way we can return only one field using findby method in Cakephp?
so far I've got this

```
$user = $this->User->findbyUsername($username, array('User.id'));
```

But it seems to return all related results....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$this->User->recursive = -1;

// If you are using the Containable behavior:
$this->User->contain();

$user = $this->User->findByUsername($username, array('fields' => 'User.id'));
```

Comment: you should put the $recursive in your app model.

Comment: I THINK what @mark is trying to say is, it's common practice to set recursive to -1 in your app model so it's then the default for all queries unless otherwise specified.  The way Doug is showing is completely fine though.

Comment: ;) thanks for elaborating my a little bit too short remark. of course dougs answer is correct in itself.